# Merge two working copies

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

All my development is in trunk. HEAD is at revision 22.
I have a second working copy created from revision 18, and I did a few changes to it.

Now I want to commit to trunk all the changes made in the second WC, and discard all the changes made in trunk (from revision 19 to 22).

How can I do that in a way that don't create conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, revert all changes from your first WC, so the WC is clean. Then do an update on that wc, so you're at r22. Now open the log (still on the first wc), select Revision 18 and choose "revert to this revision". Commit the changes. You'll get r23. Now switch to the second wc, update and then commit.

This shouldn't get you any conflicts because r23 and r18 are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps

1)from first working copy revert unwanted changes. Root of first WC
svn merge -r 22:19 {svn url}   (reverse merge)

2) svn commit -m"{ give your description on your reverse merge}"

3) from you second wc dir,
svn update   ( this will pull rev19 change)

4) from second working dir

svn commit -m"commit message for your changes"

Answer (score 0):

You can update, merge and commit everything to new revision. If you are doing it using a tool or terminal you should get that you have local updates.

*** update!

You can patch the changes and update then apply then! looh [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-patch.html)